# Set multiple environment variable to helm chart from file

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am writing an Helm Chart that should deploy a simple NGINX resource, this resource need to have all the environment variables located in an .env file.
I was wandering if is possible to cycle inside the template on some data structure and recover it in the command line the data needed.

`templates/deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.applicationName }}-{{ .Values.country }}-deployment
  labels:
    name: {{ .Values.applicationName }}-{{ .Values.country }}
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.applicationName }}-{{ .Values.country }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.applicationName }}-{{ .Values.country }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Values.applicationName }}-{{ .Values.country }}
        image: localhost:5000/{{ .Values.applicationName }}
        env:
        - name: APP_NAME
          value: "{{ .Values.applicationName }}"
        - name: COUNTRY
          value: "{{ .Values.country }}"
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Is possible use something dynamic in the env section? The Environment variables are located in a file like that and they can change.

`staging.env`

```
APP_NAME=app2-staging
APP_VERSION=1.0.2
...
...
```

Comment: You can use any of the standard Go [`text/template`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) syntax, like for example `range` loops.  The Helm documentation has some [examples of `range`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#looping-with-the-range-action) around a ConfigMap but you could adapt them to a Pod spec's `env:` block as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware how you can do it in helm directly, but you could create a secret or a configmap based on your `staging.env` file and then later use `envFrom` in your pod.

First create the secret based on the content of your file (or a configmap if the content in not sensitive):

```
kubectl create secret generic prod-secret-envs --from-env-file=staging.env
```

Then reference it in your pod in the env section:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.applicationName }}-{{ .Values.country }}-deployment
  labels:
    name: {{ .Values.applicationName }}-{{ .Values.country }}
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.applicationName }}-{{ .Values.country }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.applicationName }}-{{ .Values.country }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Values.applicationName }}-{{ .Values.country }}
        image: localhost:5000/{{ .Values.applicationName }}
        envFrom:
        - secretRef:
          name: prod-secret-envs
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```